Entire function of a given order using Hadamard's Theorem
I was trying to find if for any $\alpha > 0$ it is possible to find an entire function of that finite order. In particular, I found an answer which gives a nice solution, although I was not able to understand the second part ($\rho_* \ge 1/\alpha$) (any insight on this would be appreciated). My question is if it is possible to find such a function using Hadamard's Theorem, in particular of the form
$$f(z) = z^m w(z) e^{g(z)}$$
where $m$ is the order of the zero $z = 0$, $w(z)$ is the Weierstrass canonical product of the $z \not = 0$ zeroes of $f$ and $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree less or equals to $\rho_f$ (order of $f$).

In doing so, I used the fact that
$$\mbox{ord}(f_1 \cdot f_2) \le \max \{ \mbox{ord}(f_1) , \mbox{ord}(f_2) \}$$
and we have equality if ord$(f_1) \not = $ ord$(f_2)$. Here ord$(\cdot)$ denotes the order of an entire function.

Attempt:
Given an order $\alpha$ we want to find an $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$ with $p_f = \alpha$ of the form above. Since, ord$(z^n) = 0$, necessarily
$$p_f =  \mbox{ord}(w(z) e^{g(z)}) ,$$
so in particular
$$p_f \le \max \{ \mbox{ord}(w(z)) , \mbox{ord}(e^{g(z)}) \} .$$
If $\alpha$ is an integer, we have the functions $f(z) = z^m e^{g(z)}$ where $g(z)$ has degree $\alpha$, which (as we already knew) are of order $p_f = \alpha$ (we didn't consider $w(z)$ which means we have restricted ourselves to the search of an $f$ with no non-zero zeros).


Hence, the interesting cases are with $\alpha \not \in \mathbb{N}$. Here observations on the order seem to suggest to take $g(w)$ with degree $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ and we aim on constructing a $w(z)$ with ord$(w(z)) = \alpha$ so that by the above "order fact" we obtain an $f$ with $p_f = \alpha$. In particular this means that we have to find an appropriate sequence $\{a_j\}$ of zeroes of $f$. This is where I am struggling.
My intuition is that we want to find this sequence such that the genus is $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$: so that we have an infinite product of objects of order $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor$ which I hopefully can choose appropriately.

Any insight would be very helpful.

You can take $g=0$ as $e^g$ is not relevant - the idea with zeroes is to get them to have density (roughly) $\alpha$ in any (large enough) disc; it is much easier to use the coefficient formula for the order to construct functions of arbitrary order but zeroes can be used as above
